# Usar "->" como operator overloading

Tags: c++

He hecho un programa con dos clases

```
class Entity
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    void Print() {
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    }
};

class ScopedPtr
{
private:
    Entity* m_Obj;
public:
    ScopedPtr(Entity* entity)
        : m_Obj(entity) {}

    ~ScopedPtr() 
    {
        delete m_Obj;
    }

    Entity* operator-> () 
    {
        return m_Obj;
    }
};
```

La cosa es que yo esperaba que para llamar a la función "Print()" desde una un objeto "ScopedPtr" tuviera que hacer lo siguiente

```
ScopedPtr entity(new Entity());
(entity->)->Print();
```

Ya que dentro del paréntesis me devolvería un puntero "Entity" y con este ya podría acceder a "Print()". Pero resulta que la sintaxis correcta es poner directamente

```
entity->Print();
```

¿Alguien me puede explicar por qué esto es así?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La sobrecarga del `operator->( )` está pensada para funcionar **igual** que la forma *nativa* de dicho operador.

Piensa que, si su uso fuera distinto, el programador **debería saber**, para cada clase, si dicho operador ha sido *sobrecargado* o no. Lo cual sería inviable en código real.

- Para punteros *normales*:

  ```
  std::cout << ptr->X << '\n';
  ```
- Para clases con el operador sobrecargado:

  ```
  std::cout << (ptr->)->X << '\n';
  ```

Si eso funcionara así, sería responsabilidad **del programador** el conocer los detalles de cada clase. Que es una tarea para la que un compilador está mucho mejor dotado que nosotros :-)

Intenta siquiera pensar como se podría usar el `operator->( )` **dentro** de una plantilla, si la sintaxis dependiera del tipo. Sería totalmente inviable.

Por eso, ante una expresión del tipo `E1->E2` con el operador sobrecargado, el compilador hace por nosotros el paso intermedio:

```
( *E1.operator->( ) )
```

De forma que, desde nuestro punto de vista, `E1->E2` sigue siendo equivalente a `( *E1 ).E2`.